# How do I know if my approach to code is good or bad?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am a c++ programmer. I was trying Sieve of Eratosthenes. My program is calculating primes upto a million quickly and is in accordance to what Sieve actually is. But how do I know if there was a better way to code it or if my way of coding is bad.

Many people say try to google and compare it with how other solve it. I am not in support of that because as everyone knows, every programmer has different approach to a problem.

Link to my code: http://pastebin.com/qkrBpd29

Comment: Comments on your code you can get on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Does it work? Is the code readable? Is it maintainable? Then your solution is fine. It's likely you'll always look back on code you've written in 6 months time and do something slightly differently with newfound knowledge. Not all code you write needs to be "the perfect way of doing things". That being said, if you're looking for some feedback on code, check out [Code review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Write your code.   Go away and do other projects unrelated to this code  (that can include other software projects, renovating a home, or whatever, as long as you don't think at all about this code).    After six months, dust off your code.    If you find that the code is clear and understandable, it passes.   If you find the code a mess, it is not good code.

Comment: please do not downvote my question, I am just trying to learn... Please

Comment: @AyushMahajan: Downvotes sometimes only mean that the downvoter thinks your question is not appropriate for this site. Note that this does *not* imply the question is bad in general. BTW, I've not downvoted.

Comment: @celtschk what is more appropriate place to ask this question?

Comment: `what is more appropriate place to ask this question?` _Did_ you check out [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? To gauge anything, including code quality, you have to set up a metric. _Readable, maintainable, working_ (correct & "performant enough") ([Tas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197484/how-do-i-know-if-my-approach-to-code-is-good-or-bad/41197669#comment69594545_41197484)) go a long way; all seem to be related to _documented_.

Comment: @celtschk this question and even more so more general kind of a question like this would be blatantly off-topic over there - [too broad](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260). Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with (you even got the site name wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I just realised that your code isn't really using any of C++'s features, Only `std::cin` and `std::cout`. It's basically C code. My response below was assuming that you were working with C++.

From looking at your code I would advice that think about memory management. You've written objects with resources that don't have destruction. You are writing global functions that accept a node object, when these functions should be class functions.

Learn about smart pointers `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` from `#include <memory>` and where to use them appropriately.

If possible whenever you need something on the heap, declare something on the stack to try and ensure that it is cleaned up afterwards, this is know as RAII. (Sidenote, RAII, is a terrible name that has stuck, don't worry about what it stands for since it's not very descriptive.)

Read [Effective C++ by Scott Meyers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876) and [Effective Modern c++ Scott Meyers.](https://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj4q-bOgvvQAhUKkZQKHXm8BM8QFgghMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FEffective-Modern-Specific-Ways-Improve%2Fdp%2F1491903996&usg=AFQjCNH6Y5aYio0R2kLWKvPSFrW-4pbXRw&bvm=bv.142059868,d.dGo)

There are also some great lectures from cppcon on youtube.

- [Essentials of Modern C++ Style](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64)
- [Writing Good C++14](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OEu9C51K2A)

Comment: Thank you. I used to have this problem earlier as well, using classes skipped my mind. thank you

Comment: Something that surprised me about C++ is that struct and class have almost identical meanings. I was surprised to find out that in C++ a struct can have Destructors, Constructors, Inheritance, Functions, Private members.

The only difference is the default visibility. Class members and methods are private by default, structs are public by default.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, then your implementation is based on lists. This is not very good because you have to get to the correct positions before you can delete. I think it's much simpler to use an array instead (sorry, java code):

```
boolean[] isNotPrime = new boolean[MAX + 1];
// we know 2 is prime, it's enough to look at the odd numbers
primes.add(2); // list of primes
for (int i = 3; i < isNotPrime.length; i += 2) {
  if (isNotPrime[i])
    continue;
  primes.add(i);
  for (int j = 3 * i; j < isNotPrime.length; j += 2 * i)
    isNotPrime[j] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No code is perfect and there are many right ways to do things but asking yourself or others the following questions should help you.

1. Is my code correct? Does it produce the right answers all the time?
2. Is my code efficient?
3. Is my code maintainable? Can someone else build on it easily without having to rewrite the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
  struct Node{
   int a;
   Node* linkl;
   Node* linkr;
   }*top,*rear;
```

top and rear are globals. Not good. Globals need to be very rare and you
don't need them here.